# Cannot resolve module 'json'

Tags: json, node.js, webpack, create-react-app

I'm dealing with a very weird issue. For some reason, since a few days, my application doesn't seem to be loading JSON files anymore inside modules.

The app was created with [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app), and has been in development for a while without any issues. I've had a dependency in the project ([world-countries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/world-countries)) that basically only exports a json file. This dependency is not a recent addition.

So, here's the thing. From one day to another, I get the following error while starting/building the app:

`Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'json' in /Users/…`

As far as I know, I made no changes that would result in this, and create-react-app's webpack version is still the same.

Requiring a random JSON file in the root of my app goes well, somehow this odd behaviour only *seems* to apply to json files within node_modules in the app.

Some other points:

By this point, I have reinstalled dependencies and node.js multiple times, checked file permissions, etc. To no avail.

Another dependency that also used a json file internally also had this issue, but I managed to circumvent that.

I've explicitly installed `json-loader` in case something with webpack got messed up, but this didn't make any difference. In fact, I find it curious that _the missing dependency is "`json`" and not `json-loader`.

I have a feeling that this is a weird issue caused by some file limit, as when I run the dev server, I get errors relating to too many open files. My project isn't *that* big, so this seems weird, and I have a feeling it might have something to do with some `npm link`ed modules I have, but there is no recursion or anything.

I'm still quite perplexed, and have no idea what the issue might be. Any suggestions on how to fix this are very welcome

Comment: Try adding `!json!` to the start of import path of the json file. Example: `import somehting from '!json!../something.json';`

Comment: @zeus This is inside a module, so I don't necessarily have control over this. Still, when I do add it now, there is no difference, it seems like it knows it needs to do load the json, but can't find a module that is related to parsing json. That module, is apparently not `json-loader`, but `json`, I think.

Comment: In that case, try adding this to your webpack.config.js `{test: /\.json$/, loader: "json", include: "path/to/your/sources"}` This goes inside loaders array.

Comment: This sadly doesn't have an effect either. That said, I'm using `create-react-app`, which is rather zero-configuration. This setup so far has been working fine, so I don't think hacking this configuration would solve the problem.

Comment: Can you show a basic version of your app and post it on js fiddle or github so we can have a look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some people seemed to have had a related [issue](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1803) regarding importing json files in the past. It wasn't in a dependency but I believe it is related.

I took the time to scaffold a new project, import the `world-countries` modules and log it, and it was working fine.

I would recommend you to update re-scaffold or update all your dependencies, but most notably `react-scripts` which is version `0.9.5` for me. My `create-react-app-version` is also `1.3.0`.

Comment: Hey Aperçu, I'm confused why I didn't find this issue when searching the CRA repository, but I'm very happy you did. It led me to [pull request improving support for linked packages](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/pull/1884), which cleared things up for me. The fix isn't in yet, but you can use the fix with npm directly or use [a workaround](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1895#issuecomment-289255742) that solves the problem in the meantime. Thanks!

Comment: Ah cool! Yeah I saw this one but it still a bit strange if you need this and I don't. Are you dealing with linked department  I too? Well I guess now that you know the problem that's fine ;)

Comment: Yeah, it is weird. Still doesn't explain what made the issue appear in the first place. Not sure what would mean with “linked department I”, but I needed to split up some shared business logic across different apps, that's why the linked dependencies .

Comment: Stupid autocorrect, yeah I meant linked dependencies. I see then that explains it